# why is this showing an error in project section in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-mars

I've new installed eclipse mars(previous i used eclipse luna).I have just imported a project `a`.i paste `ojdbc.jar,servlet-api.jar`.after doing all this it is showing red error mark in the project section.

i'm giving the screenshort..[image]

and here is the java-Build path screenshorts

[image]

it is showing red error mark in the project section..
i don't know what to do..
plz help me to correct..

Comment: You should choose correct answers if they helped you. You're not giving people who answer your questions any credit at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

```
Window → Show View → Problems
```

or

```
Window → Show View → Error Log
```

Comment: i get window -> show view.but in the show view there is no any problems or error log..what should i do??plz help me sir..

Comment: You may have to look in 'Window > Show View > Other...' then 'General > Problems'